# How to seed a user identity properly in asp core2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, seeding

I have this seeding class which keeps failing to insert a record in the users table,

I believe that using CreateAsync is not proper since the method is not async the user manager does not seed the record. so I tried to seed manually using hashed password but I can't login. I am posting both methods

Why the user info is not inserted on the database initialization?
**1. Using UserManager CreateAsync**

```
       public void SeedData()
        {
            using (var serviceScope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ArtCoreDbContext>())
                {
         if (!context.ApplicationUser.Any())
                  {
               var user = new ApplicationUser
                        {
                            CityId = context.Cities.Where(g => g.Name == "Abu Nusair").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                            CountryId = context.Countries.Where(g => g.Name == "Jordan").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                             Email = "maizer85@hotmail.com",
                            FirstName = "Zaid",
                            GenderId = context.Genders.Where(g => g.Name == "Female").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                            IsActive = true,
                            LastName = "Abu Maizar",
                            MaritalStatusId = context.MaritalStatus.Where(g => g.Name == "Single").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                            NationalityId = context.Nationalities.Where(g => g.Name == "Jordanian").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                            OccupationId = context.Occupations.Where(g => g.Name == "MD").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                             PersonalPhotoUrl = null,
                             PhoneNumber = "4243244990",
                             PhoneNumberConfirmed = false,
                             PostalCode = 91335,
                             SocialSecurityNo = "AABBCC",
                            StateId = context.States.Where(g => g.Name == "Amman").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                            StatusId = context.Statuses.Where(g => g.Name == "Active").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                             UserName = "Zaid",

                        };
                         userManager.CreateAsync(user, "String@string85");
                         context.SaveChanges();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

**2. Manual Seed,**

```
         public void SeedData()
            {
                using (var serviceScope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ArtCoreDbContext>())
                    {
                        if (!context.ApplicationUser.Any())
                        {

                            context.ApplicationUser.AddRange(
                             new ApplicationUser
                             {
                                 Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                                 AccessFailedCount = 0,
                                 AdminLevel = "LA",
                                 ApartmentNo = 0,
                                 CityId = context.Cities.Where(g => g.Name == "Abu Nusair").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                                 ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                                 ContactAddress = "USA",
                                 ContactCountry = "USA",
                                 CountryId = context.Countries.Where(g => g.Name == "Jordan").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                                 DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                 Email = "maizer85@hotmail.com",
                                 EmailConfirmed = false,
                                 FirstName = "Zaid",
                                 GenderId = context.Genders.Where(g => g.Name == "Female").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                                 IsActive = true,
                                 LastLoggedIn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                 LastName = "Abu Maizar",
                                 Locality = "LA",
                                 LockoutEnabled = true,
                                 LockoutEnd = null,
                                 MaritalStatusId = context.MaritalStatus.Where(g => g.Name == "Single").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                                 NationalityId = context.Nationalities.Where(g => g.Name == "Jordanian").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                                 NormalizedEmail = "MAIZER85@HOTMAIL.COM",
                                 NormalizedUserName = "ZAID",
                                 OccupationId = context.Occupations.Where(g => g.Name == "MD").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                                 PasswordHash = HashPassword("Zaid@core85"),
                                 PersonalPhotoUrl = null,
                                 PhoneNumber = "4243244990",
                                 PhoneNumberConfirmed = false,
                                 PostalCode = 91335,
                                 SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                                 SocialSecurityNo = "AABBCC",
                                 StateId = context.States.Where(g => g.Name == "Amman").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                                  StatusId = context.Statuses.Where(g => g.Name == "Active").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                                 StreetDirection = "LA",
                                 StreetNo = "123231",
                                 TwoFactorEnabled = false,
                                 UserName = "Zaid",
                                 VerificationPhotoUrl = null

                             }
                        );
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Password Hashing Method,

```
public static string HashPassword(string password)
        {
            byte[] salt;
            byte[] buffer2;
            if (password == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
            }
            using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 0x10, 0x3e8))
            {
                salt = bytes.Salt;
                buffer2 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
            }
            byte[] dst = new byte[0x31];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, dst, 1, 0x10);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer2, 0, dst, 0x11, 0x20);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(dst);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar topic here: [Creating Asp.net Identity user in Seed method of Db Initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498921/creating-asp-net-identity-user-in-seed-method-of-db-initializer)

So you need to use non-async extension methods. Add `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` assembly and `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`.

There is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27499759/3710672

About manual seeding. I think you can't login cause the HashPassword function that you're using has different algorithm from what UserManager uses when checks password.

To make it work try to use `userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(..)` method instead of your function.

In your ApplicationUser:

```
...
PasswordHash = userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword("Zaid@core85"),
...
```

Comment: Hasher takes two args, `this.userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(ApplicationUser,Password)`

Comment: Yes, sorry I used old ASP.NET Identity and now I see that in new implementation it asks user and password.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation worked for me

```
public void SeedData()
        {
            using (var serviceScope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ArtCoreDbContext>())
                {
         if (!context.ApplicationUser.Any())
                  {
               var user = new ApplicationUser
                        {
                            CityId = context.Cities.Where(g => g.Name == "Abu Nusair").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                            CountryId = context.Countries.Where(g => g.Name == "Jordan").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                             Email = "maizer85@hotmail.com",
                            FirstName = "Zaid",
                            GenderId = context.Genders.Where(g => g.Name == "Female").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                            IsActive = true,
                            LastName = "Abu Maizar",
                            MaritalStatusId = context.MaritalStatus.Where(g => g.Name == "Single").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                            NationalityId = context.Nationalities.Where(g => g.Name == "Jordanian").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                            OccupationId = context.Occupations.Where(g => g.Name == "MD").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                             PersonalPhotoUrl = null,
                             PhoneNumber = "4243244990",
                             PhoneNumberConfirmed = false,
                             PostalCode = 91335,
                             SocialSecurityNo = "AABBCC",
                            StateId = context.States.Where(g => g.Name == "Amman").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                            StatusId = context.Statuses.Where(g => g.Name == "Active").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                             UserName = "Zaid",

                        };
                    Task<IdentityResult> createTask = userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Temp_123");
                    createTask.Wait();

                    }

                }
            }
        }
```